# "Unable to open physical file" when opening the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on a project in C#/ASP.NET and I've come across an error which I can't solve. I have a database in which I created some tables, and whenever the application tries to open the database, I get the following error:

```
"Unable to open the physical file "path\App_Data\Cars.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)". An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file path\App_Data\Cars.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."
```

I have SQL Express 2014 installed,named the instance 'SQLEXPRESS', wrote this instance ID in the Visual -> Options -> Tools -> Data Connections. In the web.config file, I have :

```
< connectionStrings>        
< add name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='path\App_Data\Cars.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>      
< add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='path\App_Data\AspnetDB.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/> 
< /connectionStrings>
```

And the way I am trying to open the database is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Cars.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
```

Can you please tell me what to do? Thanks!

UPDATE: Managed to solve it, the argument in the SqlConnection should have been the same as the ConnectionString in web.config. Now there is another one: When I try to open the default database that Visual Studio provides(with Users,Roles,ecc), I receive the following error: The database „path\App_Data\AspnetDB.mdf” cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database „path\App_Data\AspnetDB.mdf”. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
 An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file'path\App_Data\AspnetDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." Any ideas?

Comment: Do not connect to the mdf file.  You should always use the database name in the server and the server IP (name) in the connection string.  See www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly where I should modify? The AttachDbFilename in the SqlConnection instance? Thanks!

Comment: If you have another question, make another post.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from OP's edit to the question:

Managed to solve it, the argument in the SqlConnection should have been the same as the ConnectionString in web.config.